# HTML imports load order in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component, html-imports

I have a web page that renders some Polymer 1.0 custom elements.
In the `head` section of my `index.html` file I have the following:

```
<link rel="import" href="my-elements.html">
<script src="script1.js"></script>
<script src="script2.js"></script>
```

`my-elements.html` references other HTML files (via HTML imports) which in turn references javascript files using standard `script` tags.

With Chrome browser it all works as expected. The javascript files within `my-elements.html` load before `script1.js` and `script2.js`. However with Internet Explorer (v11) they load in the opposite order. i.e. `script1.js` and `script2.js` load first.

In the following article it states "HTML Imports block `<script>` elements. The `<script>` doesn’t run until its preceding imports are loaded":

https://gist.github.com/omo/9986103

So why is the ordering different with Internet Explorer?

Note that I'm using webcomponents-lite.js as my web components polyfill library. I suspect the behaviour I'm encountering is due to Internet Explorer not having native support for HTML imports, but would like to know how to work around this so that the scripts load in the intended order.

Comment: well.. according to Microsoft you should use edge (v12).. according to the rest of this planet you should use EVERYTHING ELSE instead of ie or edge.. there is no shame moving on to a better browser

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right, it's because IE is using a polyfill, so the `<link>` tag is no proceeded sequentially.

The workaround is to listen to the `HTMLImportsLoaded` event fired by the `webcomponents-lite.js` library when the HTML Import is loaded.

```
<link rel="import" href="my-elements.html">
<script>
  document.addEventListener( "HTMLImportsLoaded", function () {
    var s1 = document.createElement( "script" )
    var s2 = document.createElement( "script" )
    s1.setAttribute( "src", "script1.js" )
    s2.setAttribute( "src", "script2.js" )
    document.head.appendChild( s1 )
    document.head.appendChild( s2 )
  } )
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Marking this as the answer.